# Skills field in Google People API

Tags: google-people-api

According to the documentation, 
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#skill

it is possible to define the field "skills" when creating a contacts through the People Api. I tried to create a contact with skills populated, and the information are correctly saved in the contacts.

What the field is used for? Is it possible to display such information in Google Contacts? Is there a way to search contacts based on this field?

Thanks in advance to everybody

Answer (score 0):

Those seem to be legacy fields from GPlus days. They aren't used in any UIs. I'd recommend not using them.